# Magento 2 Extension display subcategories in block

Tags: magento2.2

I need to create new module, which allows to display subcategories for a specified category inside block.

I call the block like this:

```
<block 
  class="Vendor/Module/Block/CategoryList.php" 
  category_id="7" 
  template=Vendor_Module::CategoryList 
/>
```

Found a lot of solutions here, but couldn't make anyone work for me, I am using magento 2.2.

EDIT:
I don't know how correct this is, but I managed to get the result I wanted doing this:

categories.phtml

```
<div class="menu_categories menu_block">
<?php
$categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
$c = 0;

foreach($categories as $category) :
    $c++;

    if($c > 1) {
        break;
    } ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $category = $block->getCategory($categoryId);
            echo '<h3><a href="'.$category->getUrl().'" title="Parent Category">'.$category->getName().'</a></h3>';
            if($category->hasChildren()) {
                $subCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

                foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
                    $subCategoryObj = $block->getCategoryById($subCategory->getId());
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$subCategoryObj->getUrl().'" title="Subcategory">'.$subCategory->getName().'</a></li>';
                }
            } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

and then I call the template in the block like this:

default.xml

```
<block class="Vendor\CategoryList\Block\Categories" name="category.list" template="Vendor_CategoryList::categories.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId">
        <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="string">42</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Ẁhat are you already achieve?

Comment: What's `Block/CategoryList.php` code?

Comment: What's `CategoryList.phtml` content?

Comment: My module has this function github.com/magepow/magento2-categories follow this to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built something similar but my category list shows all store categories and the sub categories underneath for a menu. You could adjust it by passing an argument though.

> Block/Categories.php
>
> ```
> <?php
> namespace Me\My_Store\Block;
>
> class Categories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
> {
>     protected $_categoryFactory;
>     protected $_category;
>     protected $_categoryHelper;
>     protected $_categoryRepository;
>
>   public function __construct(
>         \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
>         \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
>         \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
>         \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
>         array $data = []
>     )
>     {
>         $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
>         $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
>         $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
>         parent::__construct($context, $data);
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get category object
>      * Using $_categoryFactory
>      *
>      * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
>      */
>     public function getCategory($categoryId) 
>     {
>         $this->_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
>         $this->_category->load($categoryId);
>         return $this->_category;
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get category object
>      * Using $_categoryRepository
>      *
>      * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
>      */
>     public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
>     {
>         return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Retrieve current store categories
>      *
>      * @param bool|string $sorted
>      * @param bool $asCollection
>      * @param bool $toLoad
>      * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection or
>      * \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
>      */
>     public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
>     {
>         return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get parent category object
>      *
>      * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
>      */
>     public function getParentCategory($categoryId = false)
>     {
>         if ($this->_category) {
>             return $this->_category->getParentCategory();
>         } else {
>             return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getParentCategory();
>         }
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get parent category identifier
>      *
>      * @return int
>      */
>     public function getParentId($categoryId = false)
>     {
>         if ($this->_category) {
>             return $this->_category->getParentId();
>         } else {
>             return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getParentId();
>         }
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get all parent categories ids
>      *
>      * @return array
>      */
>     public function getParentIds($categoryId = false)
>     {
>         if ($this->_category) {
>             return $this->_category->getParentIds();
>         } else {
>             return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getParentIds();
>         }
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Get all children categories IDs
>      *
>      * @param boolean $asArray return result as array instead of comma-separated list of IDs
>      * @return array|string
>      */
>     public function getAllChildren($asArray = false, $categoryId = false)
>     {
>         if ($this->_category) {
>             return $this->_category->getAllChildren($asArray);
>         } else {
>             return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getAllChildren($asArray);
>         }
>     }
>
>   /**
>      * Retrieve children ids comma separated
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function getChildren($categoryId = false)
>     {
>         if ($this->_category) {
>             return $this->_category->getChildren();
>         } else {
>             return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getChildren();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```

.

> categories.phtml
>
> ```
> <div class="row menu-links">
> <?php
> $categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
> $c = 0;
>
> foreach($categories as $category) : 
>   $c++;
>
>   if($c > 6) {
>       break;
>   } ?>
>   <div class="col-sm-2">
>       <ul>
>       <?php
>       $categoryObj = $block->getCategoryById($category->getId());
>       echo '<li class="parent"><a href="'.$categoryObj->getUrl().'">'.$category->getName().'</a></li>';
>
>       if($category->hasChildren()) {
>           $subCategories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
>
>           foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
>               $subCategoryObj = $block->getCategoryById($subCategory->getId());
>               echo '<li><a href="'.$subCategoryObj->getUrl().'">'.$subCategory->getName().'</a></li>';
>           }
>       } ?>
>       </ul>
>   </div>
> <?php endforeach;?>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: thank you very much, it works, just need to understand how to display only one category subcategories

Comment: This only get 1 sub product like, Rihards Repels said, but other than that the code works great!